# How to remove a flickering background image from a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I recorded lectures using OBS and uploaded them to Youtube. Later I found that the recorded videos flicker and show the underlying desktop image. The flickering really disturbs but it would be a huge effort to record everything from scratch.

I can extract the unwanted image from the video. Is there a way to identify this image (or parts of it) in the recorded videos and remove them? Or somehow reduce the flickering?
Here is [an example of a flickering video.](https://youtu.be/Lv5Y4uKPpLg)

I'm not very good with ffmpeg. I've tried to reduce the flicker with this

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "tblend=average,framestep=2,setpts=1*PTS" -r 10 out.mp4
```

It reduces the disco effect but leaves heavy shadows of the background image.

I also tried to identify the corrupted frames with something like this

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -r 1 -loop 1 -i background.png -filter_complex "blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=30:20" -f null -
```

but I'm not sure if it is the right approach and how to continue from this.

I believe that my command reports the frames that match the image. I thought that it would be possible to replace those frames with white and then use blending to fill in the missing bits. Ideally I'd like to do all that with a single command. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Look into the select filter with scene change scoring. Discard frames with higher scores.

Comment: I'm a complete novice with ffmpeg and not quite sure how to do that. I tried `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "select='lt(scene,0.2)'" out.mp4` and noticed that the output was slightly shortened. However, it still flickers. The videos have an audio track and I'm concerned about cutting too much away.